# Lemma, Section 3.2 of Hoffman’s Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, solution-verification, proof-writing, linear-transformations

> Let $V$ be a vector space over the field $F$; let $U$, $T_1$ and $T_2$ be linear operator on $V$; let $c$ be an element of $F$.
>
> (a) $\text{id}_V \circ U=U \circ \text{id}_V=U$;
>
> (b) $U\circ (T_1+T_2)=U\circ T_1+U\circ T_2$; $(T_1+T_2)\circ U=T_1\circ U+T_2\circ U$;
>
> (c) $c\cdot (U\circ T_1)=(c\cdot U)\circ T_1= U\circ (c\cdot T_1)$.

Proof of (a) and (b) are given in book. By theorem 6 section 3.2, $c\cdot (U\circ T_1), (c\cdot U)\circ T_1, U\circ (c\cdot T_1) \in L(V,V)$.

**My attempt:** Let $x\in V$. Then $[c\cdot (U\circ T_1)](x)$ $=c\cdot_V (U\circ T_1)(x)$ $=c\cdot_V U(T_1(x))$ $=(c\cdot U)(T_1(x))$ $=[(c\cdot U)\circ T_1](x)$. Thus $c\cdot (U\circ T_1)= (c\cdot U)\circ T_1$.

Let $x\in V$. Then $[(c\cdot U)\circ T_1](x)$ $=(c\cdot U)(T_1(x))$ $=c\cdot_V U(T_1(x))$. Since $U$ is a linear map, $c\cdot_V U(T_1(x))$ $=U(c\cdot_V T_1(x))$ $=U((c\cdot T_1)(x))$ $=[U\circ (c\cdot T_1)](x)$. Thus $(c\cdot U)\circ T_1= U\circ (c\cdot T_1)$.

In proof of $c\cdot (U\circ T_1)= (c\cdot U)\circ T_1$, we didn’t use $U$ and $T_1$ are linear maps. In proof of $(c\cdot U)\circ T_1= U\circ (c\cdot T_1)$, we didn’t use $T_1$ is linear map. **Is my proof correct?**

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: yup, and if you want to keep track of minimal assumptions, then in the proof of $(c\cdot U)\circ T_1=U\circ (c\cdot T_1)$, you only needed homogeneity of $U$ (when restricted to the image of $T_1$), additivity was irrelevant. So, you don't need the full strength of linearity of $U$.